# Motorola Blackflip Clock Doesn't Update when its Screen is off

Tags: clock, alarm

My Motorola Backflip (Android 1.6) doesn't update its clock until the screen is turned on.  This wouldn't be a problem except that the alarm won't go off in the morning unless I'm already up and checking my phone.

This problem does not occur if the phone is charging.

Is this a setting? How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

This actually sounds just like an issue that would be in MotoBLUR, especially MotoBLUR v1. This issue may have been fixed in the later releases of MotoBLUR, but initially this was a very buggy product.

If you viewed the log that android writes for any errors that occurred with the first version of BLUR (which is what is on the backflip) there are tons of errors that happen at any given moment. It seemed like Motorola rushed out the product before they were actually ready.

Comment: I've long since upgraded my phone, but if someone can verify this I'll mark the question as answered.